# exclude/include rules of rsync

Tags: linux, debian, rsync

I need to include in `rsync` rules only `.local/shares/` no other directory in `.local/` and exclude certain directories from /`.local/shares`.

My rules are currently as such:

```
+ /.local/share/
+ /.local/share/*
- /.local/share/baloo/
- /.local/share/akonadi/
- /.local/
```

But they do not seem to work. I am not sure if the manual means that i have to specifically include or subirectories of `.local/share/` such as:

```
+ /.local/share/
+ /.local/share/dir1
+ /.local/share/dir1/dir1/
+ /.local/share/dir2
+ /.local/share/dir2/dir1/dir1
+ /.local/share/*
- /.local/share/baloo/
- /.local/share/akonadi/
- /.local/
```

which is technically not really possible but in that case, is there any other "clever" solution?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your actual `rsync` command.

With this pattern file

```
- .local/share/akonadi
- .local/share/baloo
+ .local/share
- .local/*
```

and this command

```
rsync -av --include-from rsync.patterns .local destination
```

I can copy just `.local/share` without `akonadi` or `baloo`

Comment: I am on `Debian Stretch` and `man rsync` says: if  the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular spot in the hierarchy of files, otherwise it is matched against the end of the pathname. This is similar to a leading ^ in regular expressions.  Thus "/foo" would match  a  name  of  "foo" at either the "root of the transfer" (for a global rule) or in the merge-file’s directory (for a per-directory rule).  An unqualified "foo" would match a name of "foo" anywhere  in  the  tree  because  the algorithm  is  applied recursively from the top down. So I think the / is actually correct

Comment: You are probably right, I didn't try with the leading slash. Anyway, the order of the entries is important, you can't deny a more specific directory after you allowed a more general entry (the parent directory).

Comment: “if a file matches a +–Line, the search ends“ so to speak?

Comment: @FrankNocke Yes. "rsync checks each name to be transferred against the list of include/exclude patterns in turn, and the first matching pattern is acted on: if it is an exclude pattern, then that file is skipped; if it is an include pattern then that filename is not skipped"